# Matlab function find does not work on floating point

Tags: matlab, find

```
 tfinal = 10;
 dt_fine = 0.0000001;
 tvec_fine = [0:dt_fine:tfinal];
 find(tvec_fine==0.1)


ans =
Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Why does the above code not find the index where `tvec_fine` has the entry 0.1. It clearly has the entry based on the definition of `tvec_fine`.

Comment: aha, floating point precision -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

This is because floating point has a narrow precision, and 0.1 could end up being 0.10000001 vs 0.1000000002 for example.

This is a very rough description just to give you an idea, as pointed in the comments more developed answers and solutions are already available on SO.